# How to create autocomplete for city field(checkout form) Magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

Please help me - How to create autocomplete for city field(checkout form) Magento2?
How to catch click event on "city" field by knockout.js?
thanks.

---

There are two fields - country and city in checkout form. I want to implement my custom jQuery code:

I want to take country **id** from the field of the checkout form and sent it to my server than get response from the server with list of related **cities** and put them to **city** field of the checkout form with autocomplete functionality.

The main problem - where is the place where I can put my custom jQuery code in order to get the country id because the checkout form is loaded after the checkout page has loaded.

Comment: give more information, what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fields - country and city in checkout form. I want to implement my custom jQuery code:

1. I want to take country 'id' from the field of the checkout form and sent it to my server than get response from the server with list of related cities and put them to city field of the checkout form with autocomplete functionality.

**The main problem** - where is the place where I can put my custom jQuery code in order to get the country id because the checkout form is loaded **after** the checkout page has loaded.